# Accessing nginx ingress controller on port 80

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I am able to access the `nginx ingress controller` on the `NodePort`. My goal is to access the controller on `port 80`.

> Output of `kubectl -n ingress-nginx describe service/ingress-nginx`

```
Name:                     ingress-nginx
Namespace:                ingress-nginx
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
                          app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/name":"ingress-nginx","app.kubernetes.io/par...
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/part-of=ingress-nginx
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.100.48.223
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  30734/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.0.8:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  32609/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.0.8:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I have few ideas of solving that problem:

- redirect traffinc incoming on port 30734 to port 80 via `iptables`
- resize the range for nodeports so port 80 can be a nodeport as well

I am not sure if these are common ways to do this, so I'd love to hear how you usually deal with this. Probably there is another component necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to handle this is with a LoadBalancer mode service which puts a cloud load balancer in front of the existing NodePort so that you can remap the normal ports back onto it.

Comment: Ah, forgot to say that the cluster is running on a ubuntu vps server, so no cloud available.

Comment: So how to bind ingress-nginx service to port 80 in a bare-metal environment? Because LoadBalancer is available only on cloud providers.

Answer (score 0):

You should change from `NodePort` to `LoadBalancer` type for your nginx service.
Example manifest look like:

```
spec:
  ports:
  - name: nginx
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8000 // Your nginx port
  type: LoadBalancer
```